# Positioning group in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

```
BodyShadeImage= new Image(BodyShadeTexture);BodyShadeImage.setPosition(AssetsHelper.convertWidth(24),AssetsHelper.convertHeight(-68-73));Grp.addActor(BodyShadeImage);
ui.addActor(Grp);


 public void AddLstr()

            {
        i++;
            Action completeAction = new Action(){
                public boolean act( float delta ) {
                //  System.out.println("i>>>      "+i);
                    //if(i%3==0)
                    {
                         AddLstr();
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            };
                    Grp.addAction(Actions.sequence(Actions.moveBy(Grp.getX(),Grp.getY()+AssetsHelper.convertHeight(5),5f),completeAction));
                    //Grp1.addAction(Actions.moveBy(Grp.getX(),Grp.getY()+AssetsHelper.convertHeight(68),2f));

                    for(int i=0;i<PartsActual.length;i++)
                    {
                        PartsActual[i].addAction(Actions.moveBy(Grp.getX(),Grp.getY()+AssetsHelper.convertHeight(5),5f));
                    }
                System.out.println("Grp.getY()"+Grp.getY());
            }
```

Here is my code;for moving group to a fixed position.Actually i am moving group by 5pixel;but when i when i check group position.I am getting much deviation's. So group movement is not uniform.So can anyone help me to resolve this.